# How to Host PowerShell 5 from WinUI 3 C# App

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, winui-3

Hoping to get some guidance around **hosting** **PowerShell 5.1** within a C# WinUI 3 application targeting .NET 6. I've been trying numerous different NuGet packages and unfortunately, the only thing I've been able to get working will call PowerShell 7. In my case, I need to be able to call PowerShell 5.1...

Packages I've tried adding:

- Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies - Not compatible

  - Warning   NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.PowerShell.5.ReferenceAssemblies 1.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
- Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK - Only available for use with PowerShell 7, not Windows PowerShell 5.1
- PowerShellLibrary.Standard - I don't believe this is applicable for **hosting** PowerShell within an app

I can work around this a bit by just calling a new process:

```
var script = "C:\\scripts space\\MultiLineTestScript.ps1";
var process = new Process
{
     StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File \"" + script + "\"")
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
 };
 process.Start();
```

This works, but with that said I'd rather use a supported SDK or reference assembly if possible. Particularly for easier implementation of runspaces and getting the PowerShell host to run on a separate thread without hanging the UI.

I've found this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/depending-on-the-right-powershell-nuget-package-in-your-net-project/

Is it not supported/possible to host Windows PowerShell 5.1 within a WinUI 3 .net Core app? Any help would be appreciated, I am generally a PowerShell user not a C# dev but I am stumbling my way through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Hosting the Windows PowerShell SDK in a .NET (Core) application is *not* possible, as you have since confirmed [via Twitter](https://twitter.com/Steve_MSFT/status/1493319084259250176?s=20&t=cd5oTeu1Ut5mnSVQben8fg).
- Calling PowerShell in a *child process* via its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), `powershell.exe`, may indeed be your only option.

  - *Update*: See [Thomas Glaser's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74317737/45375) for an alternative that preserves the SDK experience (along with rich, but limited-by-serialization type support) via an *out-of-process runspace*; as the name suggests, a separate `powershell.exe` process is still involved, behind the scenes.

---

To start with a recap:

Since *Windows PowerShell* is based on the legacy, Windows-only .NET Framework (as opposed to its successor, the cross-platform .NET Core / .NET 5+ framework), so is the NuGet SDK package that allows hosting Windows PowerShell in an application, [`Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies/).

Your project targets .NET 6.0 (`net60`), which is why you're seeing a warning regarding the mismatch in target frameworks when you build your project.

---

While the fact that this is only a *warning*, not an error, suggests that this mismatched combination *may* situationally work nonetheless, this is *not* the case for trying to host Windows PowerShell in a .NET (Core) 6.0 application: an *exception* is thrown on trying to instantiate the `PowerShell` class: `System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.`

Using the  [`Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility) (discussed in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/connect/net-introducing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core)) doesn't help.

Therefore, calling Windows PowerShell via its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), `powershell.exe`, as a *child process* is indeed your best option.

Apart from being slower and more resource-intensive, an additional drawback is that only *text* output can be received.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option using the PowerShell SDK, which isn't exactly well documented. You can use an **Out Of Process Runspace**:

```cs
using var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(
    new TypeTable(Array.Empty<string>()),
    new PowerShellProcessInstance(new Version(5, 1), null, null, false)
);
using var instance = PowerShell.Create(runspace);
```

This allows using the full SDK, with all the benefits that brings. Under the hood this will start a Windows PowerShell process nonetheless. Of course, this will fail on any other platform than Windows.